# Approximation of function on interval

Tags: functions, approximation

I'm looking for an accurate but as simple as possible approximation of

$S(x,\lambda) = \frac{1}{(1-x) [x-(1-\lambda )]}\left((1+\lambda ) \left(\frac{x(1+\lambda)}{1-\lambda }\right)^{\frac{x(1-\lambda )-(1-\lambda )}{x(1+\lambda )-(1-\lambda )}}-\lambda -x\right)$

for $x \in (0,1), \lambda \in (0,1)$.

Does such a thing exist, and how can one find it? From what I've tried, Taylor expansion does not seem very effective in approximating the function in question... any other ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: Oh dear. How exactly did you end up with this beast?

Comment: How accurate/fast does the approximation have to be? What is the application for it?

Comment: It's an expression for "the gains of waiting" in an economics article. To be precise, it measures how much it pays for a consumer to delay his purchase, given that firms sample prices from an equilibrium distribution function $G(p)$. $\lambda$ is a parameter of the model and $x$ a variable I'd like to solve for.

Comment: Ideally I'd just like some kind of low degree polynomial, algebraic fraction or logarithmic function such that I can solve $S(x,\lambda) = W(x)$ for nice sample functions $W(x)$. I have not an extensive math background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph of $S$ as a function of $x$ looks very much like a hyperbola, which suggests using the approximation $S(x,\lambda)\approx a+\frac{b}{x+c}$ where $a,b,c$ depend on $\lambda$ in some way.

I first tried to fit a hyperbola to the data $$S(0)=\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda},\quad S'(0)=-\frac{\lambda(1+2\lambda)}{(1-\lambda)^2}, \quad S(1)=\frac{1}{2\lambda^2}\left(2\lambda-(1-\lambda^2)\ln\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}\right)$$ by solving the system $a+b/c=S(0)$, $-b/c^2=S'(0)$, and $a+b/(1+c)=S(1)$. Unfortunately this results in a substantial underestimate. The reason is that $S'(0)$ is a poor indicator of the behavior of the curve: $S'$ changes rapidly near $0$.

Then I fit the model $a+b/(x+c)$ to three points $S(0), S(1/3), S(1)$, and this worked much better.

Here is the comparison for $\lambda=0.17$ ($S$ in red, approximation in blue):

[image: first]

For $\lambda=0.37$

[image: second]

For $\lambda=0.87$

[image: third]

The coefficients $a,b,c$ are **ugly**, so I did not reproduce them here. The ugliness does not matter much if you work with specific $\lambda$. If you also need reasonably simple dependency on $\lambda$, let us know: maybe someone will come up with a better way to get  $a,b,c$.

**(Added)**

Here is an approximation with simple dependency on $\lambda$. I found it more convenient to work with $\tilde S=1-\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}S$, since this function is increasing from $0$ to something in the range 0.3..1, which is to say it has a milder dependency on $\lambda$ than the original one. I picked the model $\tilde S\approx \alpha x/(\beta x+\gamma)$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are linear functions of $\lambda$. Here is one possibility: 
$$
\tilde S\approx \frac{(1+2\lambda)x}{(2+\lambda)x+1-\lambda}
$$
This approximation is not great, but you can tweak the six (well, actually five) numeric parameters to make it look better.

Comment: I very much like the idea of fitting S(x,.) to specific, simpler functions of x. Thank you very much for putting in the effort!A simple dependency on $\lambda$ would of course be nice, but what really matters is a simple dependency on $x$ which is robust to changes in $\lambda$. In particular, a good approximation for $\lambda \approx 0$ and $\lambda \approx 1$ would be nice. I will toy around some more based on your approach!

Comment: @Martin Added a pattern for simpler approximation.

Comment: Thanks Leonid. I tried your suggestion but it only seems to give a good approximation for $\lambda$ close to zero (assuming that $S = \frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}(1-\tilde{S})$). I think I found a reasonably good approximation (with a complicated dependency on $\lambda$) to be $S(x,\lambda) = \frac{a}{x^{0.8}+b}$, with $b = \frac{2\lambda - (1-\lambda^2)Log\left(\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}\right)}{\frac{2\lambda^3}{1-\lambda}-2\lambda - (1-\lambda^2)Log\left(\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}\right)}$ and $a = \lambda b$. This function has only an exact fit for $S(0;\lambda)$ and $S(1;\lambda)$.

Comment: There is a typo in the denominator and the website doesn't let me change it. It should be $\frac{2\lambda^3}{1-\lambda}-[2\lambda-(1-\lambda^2)Log\left(\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}\right)].$